# Why I cannot set sizes on a element that is a WebComponent

Tags: html, css, web-component, native-web-component

I am trying to set `width` and `height` in a WebComponent using the `:host` selector, but the sizes do not change. Here is the template for the component:

```
<template>
  <style>
    :host {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: rebeccapurple;
    }
  </style>

  <h1>Content</h1>
</template>
```

What I need to do is adding a `div` as a container and set the size of it

```
<template>
  <style>
    div {
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       background-color: rebeccapurple;
    }
  </style>

  <div>
    <h1>Content</h1>
  </div>
</template>
```

I wanted to understand why this is not possible and the reason for it. Or if there are better way to resolve that.

Here is a JSBin of it: http://jsbin.com/gesovagapi/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default custom components are created with `display: inline;`. If you want your component to take a specified width/height, set its `display` property to `block` or `inline-block`. For example:

```
  <style>
    :host {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: rebeccapurple;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: Great explanation.. that was the problem. Thanks!